# Stein shrinkage of multiple univariate regressions

Tags: least-squares, regularization, james-stein-estimator

I have seen many papers and discussions around applying James-Stein shrinkage concept towards beta coefficients in multiple regressions and comparison of that to LASSO or Ridge. As in, for example in "The Risk of James–Stein and Lasso Shrinkage" by Hansen or "Ridge regression and James-Stein estimation - review and comments" by Draper et al.

I would like to know if it is possible (and how) to apply James-Stein shrinkage to beta coefficients if instead of 1 multiple regression (with 1-dimensional $y$ and multi-dimensional $X$) I have many univariate regressions (multi-dimensional $y$, multi-dimensional $X$) such that for each column $y_k$ I estimate univariate regression $y_k = X_k * b_k + \epsilon_k:k=1...N$. So I would like to calculate shrinkage coefficient for each $b_k$ using information about coefficients from other univariate regressions.